# G+ share not working

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am having this code ,

```
<g:plus action="share" href="{{url}}" style="height: 28px;" ></g:plus>

<script type="text/javascript">
      window.___gcfg = {
        lang: 'en-US'
      };

      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>
```

I am supposed to get a share on G+ of `url` but instead I am getting  a share of

**current url**/`url`

Why ??

Comment: Do you provide a full absolute URL including the protocol http/https in the beginning? Otherwise the URL will be treated as relative URL.

Comment: Thanks ! just added http:// to the url , it works like a charm know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending an url without `http://...` ( a relative url ) that's whay google api adds the current url to my url.

so the solution is sending an absolute url not a relative one.